# Error with dynamic email link with verification token

Tags: php, sql

I am writing a code snippet to send a email notification with a dynamic link that includes a db token.  I am receiving the email which is handled by different code but for some reason I the button will not hyperlink and I think it's because this code block is not generating the link properly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

```
   public function sendVerification2($writerID, &$errors) {
  $sql = "SELECT 
            user.`user_id` id,
            user.`email_1` email,
            user.`usr_verify_email_token` vtoken
         FROM
            `writer_split` split,
            `writer`,
            user
         WHERE
            split.`writer_id` = writer.`writer_id`
            AND
            writer.`user_id` = user.`user_id`
            AND
            split.`writer_id` = ?
         LIMIT 1      
  ";

  $user = $this->db->select($sql, array($writerID), $errors);

  if (count($errors) > 0 || count($user) === 0) {
    return;
  }

  $user = $user[0];

  //Add the change url to the the user array 
  $user[0]['verifyUserLink'] = $this->authconfig['verifyUser'] . $user['vtoken']; 

  //Send an e-mail to the user with the token 
  $this->mailer->sendTemplate($user[0]['email'], 'new_user', $user[0], $errors); 

  return count($errors) === 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where any links, or other email body text is created.

Comment: Link is generate as verifyUserLink.  So it concats token (vtoken) and appends to unique URL

Comment: I would look at this line -> `$user = $user[0];`. Don't know what library you are using, but typically `$this->db->select()` returns a single dimensional array, not a multi-dimensional one. So `$user[0]` may be returning the 1st column of the returned array (ie. `id`) which would mean that `$user['vtoken']` is essentaily doing `$user['id']['vtoken']`, which is invalid.

Comment: Thanks @Sean.  This API is written with SlimPHP.  I have a code block just before this that works fine for signups. `$this->db->select($sql, array($userID), $errors);
      if (count($errors) > 0 || count($user) === 0) {
        return;
      }
      $user = $user[0];
      //Add the change url to the the user array 
      $user['verifylink'] = $this->authconfig['verifyurlTemp'] . $user['vtoken']; 
      //Send an e-mail to the user with the token 
      $this->mailer->sendTemplate($user['email'], 'verifycom', $user, $errors); 
      return count($errors) === 0;
    }`